# How can I return the date in a custom format in this Qt/QML plasmoid?

Tags: qt, qml, kde-plasma

The digital clock in KDE Plasma 5.4.0 does not allow you to specify a custom format. I'm attempted to hack the plasmoid, which is just a QML file. However, I've been unsuccessful. There is a conditional branch, which allows you select from one of the following strings.

```
return Qt.SystemLocaleLongDate;
return Qt.ISODate;
return Qt.SystemLocaleShortDate;
```

I attempted to modify it to the following, but it's not working. Presumably I just have the syntax wrong.

```
return QDate::currentDate().toString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

How can I modify the plasmoid to show a custom date format?

### EDIT

I suspect that I might be changing the wrong line. The source code for the plasmoid I'm trying to hack is [here](http://download.kde.org/stable/plasma/5.4.0/plasma-workspace-5.4.0.tar.xz). After decompressing the file, it's specifically at `applets/digital-clock/package/`. (When installed, this directory is moved to `/usr/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.kde.plasma.digitalclock/`.) I attempted changing line 43 of `contents/ui/DigitalClock.qml`.

I attempted changing the line to `return "foo";`, but this had no effect. Again, I'm not sure if I have the syntax correct.

Comment: I'm not familair with QML. But did you try `QDate.currentDate().toString("dd.MM.yyyy")` or `Qt.QDate.currentDate().toString("dd.MM.yyyy")`. Not sure namespaces are referenced by `::`

Comment: @jpo38 Neither of those seem to work. This is my first foray into QML too, so my quoted construct was from searching the web for similar expressions.

Comment: This prints the current date as a QML `string`: `Qt.formatDateTime(new Date(), "dd.MM.yyyy")`. Don't know the actual code of the plasmoid though.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Hm… that didn't work either, but perhaps I'm reading the code wrong. I've edited my question with a link to the source. I tried changing the line to `return "foo"`, but that also didn't work, although again I'm not sure about my syntax.

Comment: Thouse first three returns do not return string, but a number (from enum).

Comment: @Arpegius Oh. Thanks. Those were the only obvious references in a language that I am unfamiliar with… do you know which lines/files I should change then?

Comment: @Arpegius Thanks for the tip. I've further investigated the code and worked out the proper section to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the line returning this value isn't a reference to the date itself, but merely specifies the format. I'm unsure of the syntax to hack the code here, but instead, you can change the code that references this property later.

```
--- DigitalClock.qml.orig   2015-08-22 20:45:40.000000000 +1000
+++ DigitalClock.qml    2015-09-01 09:32:35.417197582 +1000
@@ -515,7 +515,7 @@

         if (main.showDate) {
             if (main.tooSmall) {
-                dateLabelLeft.text = Qt.formatDate(main.currentTime, main.dateFormat);
+                dateLabelLeft.text = Qt.formatDate(main.currentTime, "dd.MM.yyyy");
             } else {
                 dateLabel.text = Qt.formatDate(main.currentTime, main.dateFormat);
             }
```